# Hide the dropdown on clicking outside of the dropdown using only css

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I worked on implementing a dropdown menu that is similar to this http://dabblet.com/gist/1507175.

The problem I am facing is, how do I close the dropdown on clicking outside of the dropdown menu, using only **css**.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That menu uses a radio button with a status of `checked` to display the dropdown content; it seems to have been intentionally designed to leave the dropdown open unless another menu item is clicked so overcoming this will be difficult.  https://purecss.io/menus/ seems to be more suited to what you want.

Comment: I think You would have to make an overlay behind the menu being a radio too. So when it gets checked the others should get unchecked

Comment: To iterate, What I am trying to achieve is a dropdown menu using checkbox hack, that opens the dropdown on checking the checkbox(invisible) and closes on re-clicking it. I am trying to also achieve closing the dropdown when we click outside of the dropdown div.

Comment: You can not do it with pure CSS only, and you have to use javascript or jquery to control the click events. Or as @derHugo said, you have to put another radio checkbox somewhere in the body and hide it. So, whenever the user clicks on the body, he unchecks the previous checkboxes.